Python subprocess.run argument passing
I'm using subprocess.run to run a script in QuPath. My python code is below, and the QuPath script is below that. The script runs but the arguments are not passed. The first code block in the script prints the recognized arguments.
When the python code is run, the QuPath script executes successfully but reports no passed arguments, and the script returns because it can't find a project path.  If the 'script' argument is placed first, the result is the same.  Thoughts appreciated!
Python code:
qupath_executable = "C:/path/to/QuPath executable"
script_path = "C:/path/to/script.groovy"
project_path = "C:/path/to/project.qpproj"

command = [
    qupath_executable,
    "-p", project_path,
    "script", script_path,
]
result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
if result.returncode == 0:
    print("Script executed successfully.")
    print(result.stdout)
else:
    print("Script execution failed.")
    print(result.stderr)

QuPath Script:
import java.awt.BasicStroke
import java.awt.Graphics2D
import qupath.ext.stardist.StarDist2D
import qupath.lib.images.servers.ImageServer
import qupath.lib.images.servers.ImageServerProvider

// Print all arguments
println "Arguments passed to the script:"
args.eachWithIndex { arg, index ->
    println "Argument ${index}: ${arg}"
}


// Retrieve the project path from the arguments
def projectPath = null
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    println "Examining argument ${i}: ${args[i]}"
    if (args[i] == "-p" && i + 1 < args.length) {
        projectPath = args[i + 1]
        break
    }
}

if (!projectPath) {
    println "Error: Project path not specified."
    return
}

def annotationOutputPath = projectPath + '/Annotations'
def annotatedImageOutputPath = projectPath + '/AnnotatedImages'
new File(annotationOutputPath).mkdirs()
new File(annotatedImageOutputPath).mkdirs()

def pathModel = projectPath + '/Models/he_heavy_augment.pb'

def stardist = StarDist2D.builder(pathModel)
      .threshold(0.5)              // Prediction threshold
      .normalizePercentiles(1, 99) // Percentile normalization
      .pixelSize(0.5)              // Resolution for detection
      .build()

println 'StarDist model initialized.'

def imageFiles = new File(projectPath + '/Images').listFiles().findAll { it.name.endsWith('.png') || it.name.endsWith('.jpg') }

if (imageFiles.isEmpty()) {
    println "No images found in the project directory."
    return
}

imageFiles.each { file ->
    println "Processing image: ${file.name}"
    
    def server = ImageServerProvider.buildServer(file)
    def imageData = server.readImageData()
    
    def pathObjects = getSelectedObjects()
    if (pathObjects.isEmpty()) {
        println "No objects selected for image: ${file.name}"
        return
    }
    println 'Selected objects: ' + pathObjects.size()
    stardist.detectObjects(imageData, pathObjects)
    println 'Object detection complete for image: ' + file.name
    
    def annotations = imageData.getHierarchy().getAnnotationObjects()
    println 'Number of annotations: ' + annotations.size()
    def json = PathIO.writeObjectToJson(annotations)
    def annotationFile = new File(annotationOutputPath, file.name + '_annotations.json')
    annotationFile.text = json
    println 'Annotations saved to ' + annotationFile.getPath()
    
    def region = RegionRequest.createInstance(server.getPath(), 1, 0, 0, server.getWidth(), server.getHeight())
    def img = ImageIO.read(server.readBufferedImage(region))
    def g2d = img.createGraphics()
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED)
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2))
    for (annotation in annotations) {
        def roi = annotation.getROI()
        def shape = roi.getShape()
        g2d.draw(shape)
    }
    g2d.dispose()
    def annotatedImageFile = new File(annotatedImageOutputPath, file.name + '_annotated.png')
    ImageIO.write(img, 'PNG', annotatedImageFile)
    println 'Annotated image saved to ' + annotatedImageFile.getPath()
}

println 'Processing complete.'


You haven't passed any arguments.  The arguments you have ("-p" and "script") are arguments to qupath, not arguments to your script.

I think you need to break this question down more by identifying if the issue is with the Python code or QuPath script. For example, if you use C:/path/to/QuPath executable -p C:/path/to/project.qpproj script C:/path/to/script.groovy on the command line, does it give the expected output? If not, then the issue is with the QuPath script and not the Python script. Which means including the Python Code is a distraction. Take a read of How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You are using a not recommended combination of arguments passed to subprocess.run. Usually:

either args is a single string and shell=True. The shell parses the command and splits it into individual args.
or args is a list(sequence) of args and shell=False.


Posix:
What is exactly happening with args being a sequence and shell=True is explained in the documentation of Popen. The result is the command like this:
/bin/sh -c upath_executable "-p" project_path "script" script_path

and the shell man page explains it further:

If  the  -c  option  is  present,  then  commands  are read from the
first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments
after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any
remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.

i.e. "-p" project_path "script" script_p is passed to the shell itself, not to the command.

Windows:
feel free to fill in the missing part

These recommendations make sense for Unix-like platforms, but the semantics of shell=True are quite different on Windows. (I'm not saying the conclusion is wrong; fortunately, I have no way to test.)

@tripleee True. Thanks for reminding me about the existence of Windows ...

Thank you, that was the problem.  Windows only seems to work with a single string, i.e., command = f'"{qupath_executable}" script -p "{project_path}" -i "{image_path}" "{script_path}"' -- whether shell is True or False.
